# PHP Script insert even if file upload/field element is disabled

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-insert

Hi I can't seem to pinpoint what's wrong. I have a form with elements. Could you check the script? I just know it lacks something but a noob like me just doesn't know. Basically when the Smart Money radio button is selected, the BPI is disabled,and vice versa. It should insert the data inputs in the db. It works fine if the selected radio btn is BPI but if Smart money was selected and the user inputs data and BPI/file upload disabled, it doesn't insert anything in the db. Can you please show me what to do I think the scripts are kinda placed wrong, because the query is below the file upload script. I think it doesn't insert anything when there is nothing to upload/that option is disabled. The file upload script interferes I guess.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename'])){
    $errors = array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['filename']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['filename']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['filename']['name'])));


    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }          

    // if no error...     
    if (empty($errors)==true) {

        // upload the file...
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = " ";
        $dbname = "admin";

        // create new record in the database
        include ("dbinfo.php");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO payment_form (Tracking, date, mode, ContactNo, totalsent, datesent, filename) VALUES ('$transactionNo', NOW(), '$rad', '$contactNo', '$totalSent', '$dateSent', '$file_name')") ;

        header('Location: paymentform_success.php');
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<form name="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="416" height="245" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Transaction No: <input type="text" name="transaction_no" id="transaction_no" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">Please select the mode of payment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="183" align="center"><input name="rad" type="radio" onclick="enableField(this)" value="Smart Money"> 
Smart Money</td>
<td width="201" align="center"><input name="rad" type="radio" onclick="enableField(this)" value="BPI"> BPI Bank Deposit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input name="contactno" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="contactno"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="filename" type="file" id="filename" disabled="disabled"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total amount sent:</td>
<td>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="totalsent" id="totalsent" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date sent:</td>
<td>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="datesent" id="datesent" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form" />

</form>
```

JS for disable/enable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enableField(obj){
    var form=obj.form;
    var txtNames=['contactno','filename'], f;
    var rads=document.getElementsByName(obj.name), r, i=0;
    while(r=rads[i++]){
        f=form[txtNames[i-1]];
        if(r.checked){
            f.removeAttribute('disabled');
            f.focus();
        }
        else{
            f.value='';
            f.setAttribute('disabled','disabled')
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're only doing the database insert if `isset($_FILES['filename'])`. if the file upload is disabled, that variable won't be set, so it won't do the DB insert.

Comment: @Barmar so what should be done sir?

Comment: What's supposed to happen when they don't upload a file? It looks like it's needed, because you have a `filename` field in the `INSERT`.

Comment: @Barmar when the file upload is disabled, that means the first option is enabled and it accepts input in the 'contactno' txtfield. Still, it should insert in the db and the filename field is left blank in the db field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the `INSERT` outside the `if(isset($_FILES['filename']))` block.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_FILES['filename'])) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['filename']['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['filename']['type'];   
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['filename']['name'])));

        $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
        if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
            $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
        }
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
        }          

        // if no error...     
        if (empty($errors)==true) {

            // upload the file...
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);

        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
    } else {
        $file_name = '';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = " ";
        $dbname = "admin";

        // create new record in the database
        include ("dbinfo.php");

        $transactionNo = $_POST['transaction_no'];
        $rad = $_POST['rad'];
        $contactNo = $_POST['contactno'];
        $totalSent = $_POST['totalsent'];
        $dateSent = $_POST['datesent'];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO payment_form (Tracking, date, mode, ContactNo, totalsent, datesent, filename) VALUES ('$transactionNo', NOW(), '$rad', '$contactNo', '$totalSent', '$dateSent', '$file_name')") ;

        header('Location: paymentform_success.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: finally it inserts! awesome sir.But before I accept your great answer,I'm getting this Notice at the top left of the page, how to remove it?
Notice: Undefined variable: transactionNo inC:\xampp\htdocs\MCC\paymentform2.php on line 56
Notice: Undefined variable: rad in C:\xampp\htdocs\MCC\paymentform2.php on line 56
Notice: Undefined variable: contactNo in C:\xampp\htdocs\MCC\paymentform2.php on line 56
...
Line 56 is the insert query line

Comment: You need to set all those variables that you have in the `INSERT` line.  e.g. `$transactionNo = $_POST['transaction_no'];`

Comment: Oh. Where should I add that code? at the very top or exactly where sir?

Comment: You can do it before the `if`, you can do it after, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: This isn't rocket science, you set variables when you know what they're supposed to be, and before you use them.

Comment: It's still there. T__T

Comment: I tried this and the notice is still there. if(isset($_POST['transaction_no'])){
    $transactionNo = $_POST['transaction_no'];
}
if(isset($_POST['rad'])){
    $rad = $_POST['rad'];
}...and so on

Comment: I've updated the answer. Everything should be inside `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`, so that this code is only executed when the form is submitted, not when you're just displaying the initial form. Then I added all the variable assignments.